# Eclipse plug in not discovered from the site where i uploaded my 'update site project' directory

Tags: maven, installation, eclipse-plugin, p2, update-site

I have an Eclipse plug-in project for which I've created a feature project and an update site project. During the build process of the update site project, I notice that certain artifacts are generated (including directories for features and plugins, site.xml, artifact.jar, content.jar, and a project file).

When I install the feature from the update site directory locally, it is recognized without any issues. However, when I upload the update site project to an official site, the same feature is not recognized

Upon reviewing other update site directories that are recognized through the site, I noticed that 'artifacts.xml.xz', 'content.xml.xz', and 'p2.index' files are missing from my directory. How can I ensure that these files are generated when building my update site project? Could the absence of these files be the reason why my feature is not recognizable when uploaded to the site, or could there be other reasons?

[Reference Picture while trying to install plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cElqW.png)

[Files that was generated while building my update site project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG0GD.png)

Comment: What do you mean by _"is not recognized"_? When you create an old style update site containing `site.xml` rather than a p2 update site, this can not directly be used in a [Tycho](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html) build which is nowadays used to build to build update sites (and you should use Tycho too).

Comment: When trying to install plug in via site by going to Help > Install New Software in the "Work with" field I provide a URL which has my update site directory. When I say 'is not recognized,' I mean that my Eclipse plugin isn't being discovered from the URL site I provided

Comment: Yes my update site contains site.xml . Could you please elaborate on how to create P2 update site and how to use Tycho?

Comment: Tycho and using it to build updates sites is covered in [this tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Basically I want to Upload my update site project to a site and provide that URL to a user to install the plug in from the URL provided. Is this not possible without Maven and Tycho?

Comment: It is possible via the export wizard but not recommended as old style update sites cannot be consumed in another Tycho build (needed to converted to a p2 update site, see e.g. [here](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/a2937a42fc74e3757d269b011e01d4702cb324cf/mirror-non-p2/pom.xml)). Maybe your update site provides the plugin not in a category, so to install it via _Help > Install New Software..._ one would have to disable _Group items by category_ in order to see it. This is why I asked you, what do you mean by _"is not recognized"_. Please show your `site.xml`.

Comment: This is my site.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<site>
   <description name="HelloWorld_UpdateSite">
      This the URL for Hello World
   </description>
   <feature url="features/HelloWorldFeature_1.0.10.8.jar" id="HelloWorldFeature" version="1.0.10.8">
      <category name="Hello_World"/>
   </feature>
   <category-def name="Hello_World" label="Hello World"/>
</site>

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments. You still didn't tell what do you mean by "is not recognized"? Which URL do you provide, where do you enter it with which options and what is then displayed? Your question does not contain this information nor a screenshot and we do not see what you see. Maybe you just missed to increment the version and in _Help > Install New Software..._ you didn't disabled _Hide items that are already installed_. But this is just guessing without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: posted picture of the error message that i receive while trying to install Eclipse plug in from the site where i uploaded my update site project directory

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows that the update site URL (in the field *Work with*) ends with `.zip`, but **instead of the ZIP archive** the **update site needs to provide the extracted files directly**.

A ZIP archive can only be used locally. In contrast, when working with a remote update site, only the necessary files are accessed, so that less has to be downloaded.

Comment: Will try as you said and get back to you

Comment: @howgler Thank you so much . Working as expected now